# I'm unable to install Cocoapods on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: cocoapods, macos-big-sur

Even After trying sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
Only single Gem is installed and after using command pod --version The output is following :

Traceback (most recent call last):
37: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' 36: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` load'
35: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>' 34: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
33: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 32: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in` <top (required)>'
31: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:77:in `<module:Pod>' 30: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
29: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/core_overrides.rb:1:in` <top (required)>'
27: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 26: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:7:in `<top (required)>' 24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:185:in` module:Pod'
23: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 22: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/trunk_source.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' 20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/trunk_source.rb:2:in` module:Pod'
19: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 18: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' 16: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
15: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.7/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent.rb:7:in` <top (required)>'
13: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 12: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.7/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executors.rb:20:in `<top (required)>' 10: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
9: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.7/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/timer_set.rb:1:in` <top (required)>'
7: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 6: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.7/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/scheduled_task.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' 4: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
3: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' 2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.7/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/ivar.rb:3:in` <top (required)>'
1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require': cannot load such file -- concurrent/collection/copy_on_write_observer_set (LoadError)

Comment: Why are you doing sudo sudo?

Comment: Sorry I typed sudo and then copied whole command